# Python OLS dealing with fixed effects

Tags: python, r, fixed, effects

I was able to make 100 fixed effects using the following code in Python.

`year_fe = pd.get_dummies(df['year'])`
`step_1 = pd.concat([df, year_fe], axis=1)`
`step_1.drop(['year'], inplace=True, axis=1)`

I am struggling to write a regression equation using all of the 100 dummies as controls for the year-fixed effect. In R, I normally use the following code '+.' to include the rest of the variables, but I can't find the equivalent in Python. Is there any equivalent of this in Python?

`L1=lm(y~x1+x2+x3+., df)`

Also, I want to format the table into LaTeX using Stargazer, but not sure how to include only one line to indicate the use of the fixed effect. The following is what I use in R.

`stargazer(l3, l33, omit = c('[y][e][a][r]'), type='text', add.lines=list(c('Year-Fixed effects', 'No','Yes')))`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks ; )